# Keeping or "caching" locally a state while refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, redux

My idea is to reduce the number of requests to the server from the web client. Say, a view/component that shows user data (first retrieved before this view/component is rendered), if the user reloads the page (F5) then the whole application is reloaded and initialized again, so another request to the server to get that data again, is there any way to maintain or "caching" that state locally?.

I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: localStorage, sessionStorage, serviceWorker all come to mind

Comment: Save the state to local storage

Comment: I was thinking on sessionStorage since it is private data, but is this a good choice for a large ammount of data (json) and how to deal with security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try redux presist link : https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist
or you can use localstorage : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, local storage is probably your best bet, but I don't think it's a very good idea. If the users reloads the page, that's essentially a blank slate for your app. You could get the data from local storage but how do you know it's still up to date? You'd need to check with the server anyway.

You should definitely look into a redux/store solution where you can store data for use *while the user is using your app*, so you can share data between components and don't have to fetch the same data every time. But actually storing it locally just reeks of bad practice, IMO.